# How to get GET request values in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, get, url-parameters

I am currently defining regular expressions in order to capture parameters in a URL, as described in the tutorial. How do I access parameters from the URL as part the `HttpRequest` object?

My `HttpRequest.GET` currently returns an empty `QueryDict` object.

I'd like to learn how to do this without a library, so I can get to know Django better.

Answer (score 848, accepted):

When a URL is like `domain/search/?q=haha`, you would use `request.GET.get('q', '')`.

`q` is the parameter you want, and `''` is the default value if `q` isn't found.

However, if you are instead just configuring your `URLconf`**, then your captures from the `regex` are passed to the function as arguments (or named arguments).

Such as:

```
(r'^user/(?P<username>\w{0,50})/$', views.profile_page,),
```

Then in your `views.py` you would have

```
def profile_page(request, username):
    # Rest of the method
```

Comment: Is '?param=' the only way Django recognizes parameters? Is there a way to use URLconf with HTTP.GET? I'd like to do /param/2.

Comment: Check the second part of my response regarding your URLconf and regex captures.

Comment: Ok. I am currently using the second method. Seems like they are separate mechanisms, and I'm trying to blend them. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. use request.GET if you submit a form using GET, use request.POST if you submit a form using POST, and if you just want to configure URLs to have variable sections, then it's a URLconf/view argument.

Comment: What about class based views?

Comment: for class based views you can use `self.kwargs['parameter']`

Comment: what if there are more than  one parameter? For eg. pagination with two query params limit and skip

Comment: how can i detect from the template, the presence of a query parameter? or must I do this in views.py

Comment: @Akin `{% if request.GET.the_var_you_want %}`

Comment: @RoyendgelSilberie Go on...

Answer (score 446):

To clarify [camflan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22445/camflan)'s [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/150518/11573842), let's suppose you have

- the rule `url(regex=r'^user/(?P<username>\w{1,50})/$', view='views.profile_page')`
- an incoming request for `http://domain/user/thaiyoshi/?message=Hi`

The URL dispatcher rule will catch parts of the URL *path* (here `"user/thaiyoshi/"`) and pass them to the view function along with the request object.

The query string (here `message=Hi`) is parsed and parameters are stored as a `QueryDict` in `request.GET`. No further matching or processing for HTTP GET parameters is done.

This view function would use both parts extracted from the URL path and a query parameter:

```
def profile_page(request, username=None):
    user = User.objects.get(username=username)
    message = request.GET.get('message')
```

As a side note, you'll find the request method (in this case `"GET"`, and for submitted forms usually `"POST"`) in `request.method`. In some cases, it's useful to check that it matches what you're expecting.

**Update:** When deciding whether to use the URL path or the query parameters for passing information, the following may help:

- use the URL path for uniquely identifying resources, e.g. `/blog/post/15/` (not `/blog/posts/?id=15`)
- use query parameters for changing the way the resource is displayed, e.g. `/blog/post/15/?show_comments=1` or `/blog/posts/2008/?sort_by=date&direction=desc`
- to make human-friendly URLs, avoid using ID numbers and use e.g. dates, categories, and/or slugs: `/blog/post/2008/09/30/django-urls/`

Comment: This is a really well written answer.  It sure helped me understand Django a bit better.

Comment: how can we get all parameters values without mentioning names

Comment: @numerah request.GET is a Python dictionary. You can e.g. iterate through request.GET.items().

Comment: any reasons why it's preferred to follow the habits written in the update ? (when to use URL path vs GET params)

Comment: @m0etaz genuinely good question.  I think you'd have a hard time finding the origin of this concept.  From my experience this was something handed down to me in an almost tribal way, i'd be curious to find the origin as well.

Answer (score 87):

Using GET

```
request.GET["id"]
```

Using POST

```
request.POST["id"]
```

Comment: While this works for existing keys, the answers by camflan and akaihola have used .get() to avoid `KeyError` exceptions in the case of a missing key. It would be wise to do the same (e.g. `request.POST.get('id', '')`).

Answer (score 67):

Someone would wonder how to set path in file *urls.py*, such as

```
domain/search/?q=CA
```

so that we could invoke query.

The fact is that it is *not* necessary to set such a route in file *urls.py*. You need to set just the route in *urls.py*:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('domain/search/', views.CityListView.as_view()),
]
```

And when you input http://servername:port/domain/search/?q=CA. The query part '?q=CA' will be automatically reserved in the hash table which you can reference though

```
request.GET.get('q', None).
```

Here is an example (file *views.py*)

```
class CityListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = CityNameSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        if self.request.method == 'GET':
            queryset = City.objects.all()
            state_name = self.request.GET.get('q', None)
            if state_name is not None:
                queryset = queryset.filter(state__name=state_name)
            return queryset
```

In addition, when you write query string in the URL:

```
http://servername:port/domain/search/?q=CA
```

Do not wrap query string in quotes. For example,

```
http://servername:port/domain/search/?q="CA"
```

Comment: Hi Eric! I am new to Django. Can you shed more light on "queryset = queryset.filter(state__name=state_name)". What does the double underscore in state__name signify.

Comment: Here "state" is a table and "name" is a filed in this table. In the filter of Django, state__name will reference the value of field  "name" in "state" table.

Answer (score 33):

```
def some_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    if kwargs.get('q', None):
        # Do something here ..
```

Answer (score 31):

For situations where you only have the `request` object you can use `request.parser_context['kwargs']['your_param']`

Answer (score 27):

You have two common ways to do that in case your URL looks like that:

```
https://domain/method/?a=x&b=y
```

Version 1:

If a specific key is mandatory you can use:

```
key_a = request.GET['a']
```

This will return a value of `a` if the key exists and an *exception* if not.

Version 2:

If your keys are optional:

```
request.GET.get('a')
```

You can try that without any argument and this will not crash.
So you can wrap it with `try: except:` and return `HttpResponseBadRequest()` in example.
This is a simple way to make your code less complex, without using special exceptions handling.

Comment: how can i detect query param from the template?

Answer (score 17):

I would like to share a tip that may save you some time.
If you plan to use something like this in your `urls.py` file:

```
url(r'^(?P<username>\w+)/$', views.profile_page,),
```

Which basically means `www.example.com/<username>`. Be sure to place it at the end of your URL entries, because otherwise, it is prone to cause conflicts with the URL entries that follow below, i.e. accessing one of them **will** give you the nice error: `User matching query does not exist.`
 
I've just experienced it myself; hope it helps!

Comment: Plus, in this case you may want to check that user names do not collide with other url enrties.

Answer (score 14):

These queries are currently done in two ways. If you want to access the query parameters (GET) you can query the following:

```
http://myserver:port/resource/?status=1
```

```
request.query_params.get('status', None) => 1
```

If you want to access the parameters passed by POST, you need to access this way:

```
request.data.get('role', None)
```

Accessing the dictionary (QueryDict) with 'get()', you can set a default value. In the cases above, if 'status' or 'role' are not informed, the values ​​are None.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't know the name of params and want to work with them all, you can use `request.GET.keys()` or `dict(request.GET)` functions

Answer (score 9):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but [this snippet](http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/826/) is helpful for managing `query_strings` in `templates`.

Answer (score 9):

If you only have access to the view object, then you can get the parameters defined in the URL path this way:

```
view.kwargs.get('url_param')
```

If you only have access to the request object, use the following:

```
request.resolver_match.kwargs.get('url_param')
```

Tested on Django 3.

Answer (score 8):

#### views.py

```py
from rest_framework.response import Response

def update_product(request, pk):
    return Response({"pk":pk})
```

**pk** means **primary_key**.

#### urls.py

```py
from products.views import update_product
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    ...,
    path('update/products/<int:pk>', update_product)
]
```

Comment: I think this is the most clean way to write a path, you can extend more about the answer like explaining a little bit about optional parameteres an document and explain a little the pieces of code added, just to pleople who are new in the framework.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I really appreciate it so much. :) .URL Parameters can not be optional (As far as I think). because they specify which function will be executed. what can be optional is Query Parameters and  data in request body. this can be controlled via a serializer (In Django REST Framework). @allexiusw

Comment: Of course they can, you have to use: `def update_product(request, pk=None):` the pk is gona be optional...

Comment: You are correct. :) :) But, I am afraid this may create an endpoint like this: `update/products//`, with double slash in the end, because it is empty. Then path should be like this: `path('update/products/<int:pk>', update_product)`, not like this: `path('update/products/<int:pk>/', update_product)`, I have updated it. I removed the last slash in the answer of the question. The differrenece is the last slash. :) :)

Comment: I am so glad you made me realize this. :) :) I didn't realize it before. :) :)

Answer (score 6):

You might as well check request.META dictionary to access many useful things like
PATH_INFO, QUERY_STRING

```
# for example
request.META['QUERY_STRING']

# or to avoid any exceptions provide a fallback

request.META.get('QUERY_STRING', False)
```

you said that it returns empty query dict

I think you need to tune your url to accept required or optional args or kwargs
Django got you all the power you need with regrex like:

```
url(r'^project_config/(?P<product>\w+)/$', views.foo),
```

more about this at [django-optional-url-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14351048/django-optional-url-parameters#answer-14351174)

Answer (score 5):

This is another alternate solution that can be implemented:

In the URL configuration:

```py
urlpatterns = [path('runreport/<str:queryparams>', views.get)]
```

In the views:

```py
list2 = queryparams.split("&")
```

Comment: Helped me to understand, I can pass int by "<int:some_number>"

Answer (score 2):

It seems more recommended to use `request.query_params`. For example,

When a URL is like `domain/search/?q=haha`, you would use `request.query_params.get('q', None)`

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

"request.query_params is a more correctly named synonym for request.GET.

For clarity inside your code, we recommend using request.query_params instead of the Django's standard request.GET. Doing so will help keep your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may include query parameters, not just GET requests."

Answer (score 1):

url parameters may be captured by `request.query_params`

Comment: Please, consider a better elaboration for your anwsers...A little context of something. Thx

Answer (score 0):

In Django, views gets the path resolved for you.

But other than that if you need to resolve the path you can use the resolve module

Ex - the requestedPath is - `domain/search/?userName=myUserName`
or `domain/search/<userName>/product/<productName>`

```
from django.urls import resolve
resolveMatcher = resolve(request.path)
userName = resolveMatcher.kwargs.get('userName', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you access the url below:

```
https://example.com/?fruits=apple&meat=beef
```

Then, you can get the parameters in `views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106783/how-to-get-url-parameter-list-in-django/77129778#77129778) explains how to get a `GET` request values' list in Django and [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336548/django-taking-values-from-post-request/77136495#77136495) explains how to get `POST` request values in Django:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    print(request.GET['fruits']) # apple
    print(request.GET.get('meat')) # beef
    print(request.GET.get('fish')) # None
    print(request.GET.get('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.GET.getlist('fruits')) # ['apple']
    print(request.GET.getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.GET.getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.GET._getlist('meat')) # ['beef']
    print(request.GET._getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.GET._getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(list(request.GET.keys())) # ['fruits', 'meat']
    print(list(request.GET.values())) # ['apple', 'beef']
    print(list(request.GET.items())) # [('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.GET.lists())) # [('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.GET.dict()) # {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.GET)) # {'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}
    print(request.META['QUERY_STRING']) # fruits=apple&meat=beef
    print(request.META.get('QUERY_STRING')) # fruits=apple&meat=beef

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Then, you can get the parameters in `index.html` as shown below:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

{{ request.GET.fruits }} {# apple #}
{{ request.GET.meat }} {# beef #}
{{ request.GET.dict }} {# {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }} {# fruits=apple&meat=beef #}
```