# How should I convert this long and complex PHP style URL query string to a Django url?

Tags: python, django, url, url-routing

I'm converting a small PHP application to Django.

One section has a long query string, indicating how a widget is to be displayed. There are a few required parameters and several optional ones.

The current urls read like:

```
app.php?id=102030&size=large&auto=0&bw=1&extra=1
```

The id and size are required, but auto, bw and extra are optional. I use defaults if they're not specified.

My first idea was to make a django URL pattern with the required info, id and size:

```
url(r'^/app/(P?<id>)\d+/(P?<size>)\w+$',app.project.views.widget,name='swidget')
```

The optional parameters would then be a query string, like

```
/app/102030/large?auto=0&bw=1&extra=0
```

Is it a common practice to mix GET parameters with parameters defined in the URL conf in Django? Or should I make it like

```
url(r'^/app/(P?<id>)\d+/(P?<size>)\w+/(P?<auto>)\d/(P?<bw>)\d/(P?<extra>)\d[/]?,'app.project.views.widget,name='swidget')
#so it would look like:
/app/102030/large/0/1/0/
```

Any suggestions about best practices or issues to keep in mind with either style are appreciated!

Comment: I also found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/django-capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get which covers similar issues.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you consider that "URL" stands for Uniform *Resource* Locator, the URL should only indicate the resource being displayed, and any 'configuration' options should be passed as parameters. So, I think your first idea is fine.

Comment: That's a good insight. So, the parameters that would represent a truly different resource if changed should be in the URL definition, and the minor ones (autoplay or not, etc) can be GET params.

Comment: I think so. Particularly if those minor parameters are optional, or can have meaningful default values.