# How to get GET request values in Django Templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, get, url-parameters

Is it correct to say that there is no simple tag that just writes some http get
query parameter?
If all needed is printing a http get query parameter e.g. `?q=w`
can I directly use the value q with a template tag or need the copy
the value in the request handler?
Is it possible to more directly pass values (all values) from http get
to template?
Because copying every value seems repeating the same handling many
times

```
template_values = {'q':self.request.get('q'),...
```

It should be possible to iterate the parameter set. Can you recommend
that or any other solution?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You don't need to do this at all. The request is available in the template context automatically (as long as you enable the [request context processor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext) and use a RequestContext) - or you can just pass the request object directly  in the context.

And `request.GET` is a dictionary-like object, so once you have the request you can get the GET values directly in the template:

```
{{ request.GET.q }}
```

Comment: How to add it in a if condition ?

Comment: Is there a way to add an optional default value in the template? For example, request.GET.get("q", True).

Comment: @Root Use `{% if 'q' in request.GET %}` before retrieving the value. If you wanted to use a default value if `q` is not present, you can tag on an `{% else %}`.

Comment: For later Django versions (maybe > 2.0) this seems to be `{{ request.GET.urlencode }}`

Answer (score 1):

For example, if you access the url below:

```
https://example.com/?fruits=apple&meat=beef
```

Then, you can get the parameters in Django Templates as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129172#77129172) explains it more:

```html
{# "index.html" #}

{{ request.GET.fruits }} {# apple #}
{{ request.GET.meat }} {# beef #}
{{ request.GET.dict }} {# {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'} #}
{{ request.META.QUERY_STRING }} {# fruits=apple&meat=beef #}
```