# How to get GET request values in Django Views?

Tags: python, django, django-views, get, url-parameters

Suppose I have a url that has php style parameters, that is:

```
http://example.com/blah?param1=val1&param2=val2
```

And, I want to place their values into the generated HTML of the template.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: FYI: These are not "PHP style parameters", these are normal GET parameters.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

`{{request.GET.param1}}` in the template. (Using [RequestContext](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext))

`request.GET.get('param1', None)` in the view.

Answer (score 25):

```
{{ request.resolver_match.kwargs.argument }}
```

for function arguments passed to the view as:

```
def myview(request, argument):
```

Tested on Django 1.9.

Answer (score 8):

Suppose you have GET Method like this -

> http://djangopmt.localhost/tasks/?project=1&status=3&priority=High&search=StudyGyaan.com

We can get the URL Parameters like this in Django Template -

```
{{request.GET.project}}
{{request.GET.status}}
{{request.GET.priority}}
{{request.GET.search}}
```

And if you want to get URL parameter in Django Views then you can get it like this -

```
request.GET.get('project', None)
request.GET.get('status', None)
request.GET.get('priority', None)
request.GET.get('search', None)
```

Comment: .get('param', None) do not need to have this None. It's the default, so redundant

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you access the url below:

```
https://example.com/?fruits=apple&meat=beef
```

Then, you can get the parameters in `views.py` as shown below. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-request-get-in-django/77129172#77129172) explains it more:

```py
# "views.py"

from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):

    print(request.GET['fruits']) # apple
    print(request.GET.get('meat')) # beef
    print(request.GET.get('fish')) # None
    print(request.GET.get('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.GET.getlist('fruits')) # ['apple']
    print(request.GET.getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.GET.getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(request.GET._getlist('meat')) # ['beef']
    print(request.GET._getlist('fish')) # []
    print(request.GET._getlist('fish', "Doesn't exist")) # Doesn't exist
    print(list(request.GET.keys())) # ['fruits', 'meat']
    print(list(request.GET.values())) # ['apple', 'beef']
    print(list(request.GET.items())) # [('fruits', 'apple'), ('meat', 'beef')]
    print(list(request.GET.lists())) # [('fruits', ['apple']), ('meat', ['beef'])]
    print(request.GET.dict()) # {'fruits': 'apple', 'meat': 'beef'}
    print(dict(request.GET)) # {'fruits': ['apple'], 'meat': ['beef']}
    print(request.META['QUERY_STRING']) # fruits=apple&meat=beef
    print(request.META.get('QUERY_STRING')) # fruits=apple&meat=beef

    return render(request, 'index.html')
```