# How to store user input in a variable in django python

Tags: python, django, database, orm, user-input

So i want to take the user input and compare it to data present in the sqlite3 db, and if matches I'd like to print that whole row, using django orm.

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Inventory(models.Model):
    item_bc = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    item_details = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('search', views.search, name='search'),
]
```

views.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from models import Inventory

# Create your views here.


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'form.html')


def search(request):
    search_input = request.POST.get('barcode')
    data = Inventory.objects.filter(item_bc=search_input).values()
    return render(request, 'result.html', {"data": data})
```

I really appreciate your time and help, thank you!

i think adding logic to the search function to compare should work but extremely new to django and dont really know on how to start..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django and query string parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3711349/django-and-query-string-parameters). Better target: [How to get URL parameters in a Django view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225130/how-to-get-url-parameters-in-a-django-view)

Answer (score 0):

html

```
<form action="search" method="post">
    BARCODE: <input type="text" name="barcode">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

in view.py you can fetch searched input like this and filter.

```
def search(request):
    search_input = request.POST['barcode']
    data = ModelName.objects.filter(fieldname__icontains=search_input)
    return render(request, 'result.html', {"data":data})
```

Comment: Hey there, so i tried the solution and now the problem is when i try to run the whole thing i get different error all associated with the line "data = modelname.objects.filter thing i think my database is not getting connected or something like that, if u can please help

Comment: can you share error ?and the code you tried also

Comment: this is the code you gave and i edited it slightly

Comment: and this is giving me Attribute error saying nonetype object has no attribute filter..

Comment: update the question with Fresh code and Models.

Comment: I have updated the code, also have added the models.py

Comment: code should work. still getting an error? did you check you're getting input in this `search_input = request.POST.get('barcode')`  try to print `search_input`

Comment: now everything else is fine but I am unable to import the inventory which is my modelclass in the view.py it is not allowing me to import showing error and not recognizing the file

Comment: yea, that is working fine but the query set which filters the results needs to use my model class which i created in models.py now i am unable to import that model and when i do i get errors..

Comment: do this `from appName.models import Inventory`.