# How to get SMS sender info using python?

Tags: python, django, sms, twilio

I'm using Twilio and Django for an SMS application (I started learning Python yesterday, be gentle).

Here's what I need help with:
When Twilio sends an incoming SMS message to my URL, I want my app to automatically add the incoming phone number, date/time, and incoming message to some lists. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Twilio sends it as the 'From' parameter when it requests your URL.  The documentation is at: http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/sms/message

It will be similar to this code, I wrote this in webapp with python (not Django).

```
class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):  

  def get(self):
    model = Storage()
    from = self.request.get("From")
    if from is not '':
      model.sms_from = self.request.get("From")
      model.sms_body = self.request.get("Body")
      model.put()

    models = Storage.all()

    for i in models:
      self.response.out.write(i.sms_from + ' ' + i.sms_body +'<br>')
```

UPDATE:

When I get my phone and send a text to xxx-xxx-xxxx, twilio will receive that text and then make a request to the URL I configured.

From that point it looks exactly the same as a request from a web browser.

This question will help you with the specifics with Django
[Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/django-capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

There should be all the parameters you need from the sender.

Comment: Sorry if this is a silly question, but how do I connect all that to Twilio's request of my URL? I don't know what it means codewise for Twilio to request my URL. Is that MainHandler a function? And Twilio's request is the input for that function?

Comment: In your twilio account, you setup a URL that you want twilio to request when there is an incoming SMS message.  That URL will have the 'From' parameter with it (along with tons more).

Comment: Thanks for the reply
I get that. 

What I'm asking is how do I get the program to know that it's supposed to get that information from Twilio's request? Kinda like how you have to have some sort of raw_input('Type your name here:') statement in order to get input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a sample app using Twilio and Django on [GitHub](https://github.com/synedra/django-linkedin-simple), but here's the specific answer you're looking for.

For this example I'm using the '/reply/' URL on my server (and have told Twilio that's where to POST to)

In urls.py you're just going to do a standard mapping:
url(r'^reply', 'twilio_sms.views.sms_reply'),

Here's a really basic response to the user, responding with what the Twilio server expects.
def sms_reply(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        params = request.POST
        phone = re.sub('+1','',params['From'])

```
    response_message =  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8">'
    response_message += '<Response><Sms>Thanks for your text!</Sms></Response>'
    return HttpResponse(response_message)
```

In my code I actually build the XML response using a library, which I suggest in general, but for a code sample it's too much information.