# Django url regex parameter capturing

Tags: python, django

I want to route the following uri to a view;

`localhost:8000/?tag=Python`

to

`def index_tag_query(request, tag=None):`

in my url conf, I've tried the following regex patterns but none seem to be capturing the request even though the regex looks good;

`url(r'^\?tag=(?P<tag>\w+)/$', 'links.views.index_tag_query'),`

`url(r'^\/?\?tag=(?P<tag>\w+)/$', 'links.views.index_tag_query'),`

`url(r'^\/?\?tag=(?P<tag>.*)/$', 'links.views.index_tag_query'),`

What gives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't parse GET parameters from your URLconf. For a better explanation then I can give, check out this question (2nd answer): [Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Basically, the urlconf parses and routes the URL to a view, passing any GET parameters to the view. You deal with these GET parameters *in the view itself*

**urls.py**

```
url(r^somepath/$', 'links.views.index_tag_query')
```

**views.py**

```
def index_tag_query(request):
    tag = request.GET.get('tag', None)
    if tag == "Python":
         ...
```

Comment: Cool. I tried that approach originally but felt there was a better way to achieve it in the URL conf. I have now changed the URI to be `url(r'^tag/(?P<tag>.*)/$', 'links.views.index_tag_query', name='tag-search')` which works great and removes the need for extra conditionals inside a view function.

Comment: Yea, that's the best way of doing it. I think it's a good idea to use your URLs to construct the queryset (i.e. what data to grab), and GET parameters to adjust it (how to return it - sorting, exlclusions etc)