# Django url pattern - string parameter

Tags: python, regex, django

Django url pattern that have a number parameter is:

```
url(r'^polls/(?P<poll_id>\d+)/$', 'polls.views.detail')
```

What will be the correct syntax if my poll_id is not a number but a string of character?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Depends on what characters you care about. Like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) say, `\w` will give you an alphanumeric character or an underscore.

Comment: thanks man! i have try using \s i didn't know its \w. thank you again.

Answer (score 64):

In newer versions of Django such as 2.1 you can use

```
path('polls/<str:poll_id>', views.polls_detail)
```

as given here [Django URL dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/)

```
def polls_detail(request,poll_id):
#process your request here
```

Comment: with this answer you can basically then request 'http://url.com/polls/123'. How can one create a url such that you can send a request 'http://url.com/polls?poll_id=123' ?

Comment: Just create a path with polls and then you can add anything in query params.

Comment: @FedericoCapaldo see https://stackoverflow.com/a/150518/13163131

Answer (score 55):

for having a string parameter in url you can have:
 url like this:

```
url(r'^polls/(?P<string>[\w\-]+)/$','polls.views.detail')
```

This will even allow the slug strings to pass
eg:strings like node-js etc.

Answer (score 20):

Starting in Django 2.0 it is easier to handle string parameters in URLs with the addition of the *slug* symbol, which is used just like int in **urls.py**:

```
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('something/<slug:foo>', views.slug_test),
]
```

And in your function-based or class-based view you would handle it just like any other parameter:

```
def slug_test(request, foo):
    return HttpResponse('Slug parameter is: ' + foo)
```

Comment: The slug type won't work if the name contains underscores, cuz the slug expects it to be hyphen-separated. But it's a good answer if that's what you want

Answer (score 10):

From Django 2.0 onward, `path` has been introduced. `path` does not take reg ex in urls, hence it is meant to be a simplified version of the older `url`

From 2.0 onward you can use path instead like below :

```
path('polls/<poll_id>', views.polls_detail)
```

string path parameters need not be explicitly specified, as default data type for path parameters is string itself.

Ref : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#whats-new-2-0

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Django version >= 2.0, then this is done simply like below.

```
from django.urls import path    

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('polls/<string>/$','polls.views.detail')
    ...
]
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urls/#django.urls.path

Comment: There is `slug`, `int` and `username` in angle brackets, but not `string`. And a datatype must be followed by `:` and the `keyword` I think. So your example might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In case your angle-bracket argument is a path, i.e. contains "/", you'll have to use `path:`.

Example:
`path('section/<path:some_path>,app.views.some_view,name='some_name')`

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters

(EDITED)
"str - Matches any non-empty string, EXCLUDING the path separator, '/'. This is the default if a converter isn’t included in the expression.

slug - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, building-your-1st-django-site.

path - Matches any non-empty string, INCLUDING the path separator, '/'. This allows you to match against a complete URL path rather than a segment of a URL path as with str."