# django custom blog post urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, url-pattern

I am learning django by building a simple blogging app. While its all but done,  I currently have individual posts having a url in the format `https://my_site_dot_com/blog/entry/38/` where the number 38 corresponds to the primary key of said post.
What i want is it to have the format `https://my_site_dot_com/blog/entry/this_is_custom_title/` where  "this_is_custom_title" corresponds to the heading of the post. I have no idea how to accomplish this. Can anyone offer any assistance?
My model looks like:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entry_text = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="media", blank=True)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entry_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

        class Meta:
            verbose_name_plural = "blog"
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.entry_title
```

I want the entry_title to the the custom url instead of the primary key.

My `urls.py` looks like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name="blog-home"),
    path('entry/<int:pk>/', EntryView.as_view(), name="entry-detail"),
    path('create_entry/', CreateEntryView.as_view(success_url='/'), name='create_entry'),
]
```

Edit:
The class handing the post looks like this:

```
class EntryView(DetailView):
    model = Entry
    template_name = 'blog/entry_detail.html'
    data_set = random_info()
    stuff_for_post = {
        "info": data_set
    }

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['rand_im'] = random_image()
        context['tags'] = ['tag1','tag2','tag3']

        return context
```

I'm an absolute noob in django and come from android/java. So please give an easy to understand explanation.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a slug field to your **Entry** model and a **get_absolute_url** method. Don't forget to import **reverse** function from Django's url module.

```py
from django.urls import reverse

class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entry_text = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="media", blank=True)
    entry_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    entry_author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('entry_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "blog"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.entry_title
```

Then, within the **urls.py** module of your app, add the following url pattern to the **urlpatterns** list. Don't forget to load the corresponding view, I guess it may be **EntryView** in this case.

```py
from django.urls import path
from .views import EntryView

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('<slug:slug>', EntryView.as_view(), name='entry_detail'), # new
    ...
]
```

Then the slug should replace the primary key pattern in the url.

To go a bit further, you can use a method within your model that slugify your title for instance. (define the method within the model then call it from the ****save**** method of the model, by overriding the save method)

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify

Comment: this doesnt seem to work. The url pattern now looks like http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2 and i get the error Page not found (404). What could be wrong?

Comment: the whole error is Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/2
Raised by: blog.views.EntryView
No entry found matching the query

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Class Based View you should  use a slug.
First add a new field entry_slug to your Entry model and override the save method in order to automatically generate the entry_slug field:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    entry_slug = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.entry_slug = slugify(self.entry_title )
            super(Entry, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

You can do by replacing the pk with entry_slug:

```
path('entry/<slug:entry_slug>/', EntryView.as_view(), name="entry-detail")
```

Comment: when i do this, i get this error: Generic detail view EntryView must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are passing an integer through your url. All you need to do is modify this slightly to pass a string through the url. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11894916/django-url-pattern-string-parameter) is a similar question that discusses how to accomplish this.

As for changes you need to make in your code, `urls.py` will need to be updated

```
path('entry/<str:title>/', EntryView.as_view(), name="entry-detail")
```

You haven't provided your blog post view, but it will then look something like this:

```
def post(request, title):
    template = "template.html"
    post = Posts.objects.filter(entry_title==title)
    return render(request, template, {'post':post})
```

Comment: i am using the class based approach. I've edited my question to show what the class looks like. How do i proceed?