# Can't fetch offset value in the URL （Django）

Tags: python, django, url, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

I'm designing a detail page of my website by using django, and set the Topic Url as following:

```
(r'd/\d+/$', 'xiangwww.detail.views.detail'),
```

the second argument is the ID of the topic.
But when I fetch it following the guide of Django Book :

```
def detail(request,offset):
    print offset
    return render_to_response('detail.html')
```

The page "localhost:8000/d/1/" in  shows the TypeError:
 detail() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

It seems Django can't recognise what is offset in my views.py file, how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *capture* the number, by putting it in a regular expression group:

```
(r'd/(\d+)/$', 'xiangwww.detail.views.detail'),
```

Without the `(...)` group, Django does not know about the captured number and cannot pass it to your view. See the [URL Dispatch documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions):

> To capture a value from the URL, just put parenthesis around it.

Comment: is there any possibility to pass more than two arguments as offsets?

Comment: Sure, just create more `(..)` groups; the linked documentation has some examples that use multiple capturing groups.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change url to accept offset as parameter e.g.

```
(r'd/(?P<offset>\d+/)$', 'xiangwww.detail.views.detail'),
```