# How does django parse url queries?

Tags: django, url

How do django views parse url queries? For example, suppose I have a view that lists all of the users at

```
localhost:8000/users/
```

If I wanted to add my own pagination feature, without django's built in one, how would I handle

```
localhost:8000/users/?page=10
```

or

```
localhost:8000/users/?id=526
```

I know that this defies that traditional sense of pretty url's, but I feel that it is necessary at some points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`request.GET`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects).[`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET):

```
fallback_page_num = '1'
page = request.GET.get('page', fallback_page_num)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just give a look at the official documentation: [URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/)

Or look at this: [Capturing the URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)