# How can I handle query "?" in my django urls.py

Tags: python, regex, django, httprequest, django-urls

I am new to Django. I have to write a moke. My server will look at a specific address. 
Like this:

`portal/client_api.ashx?client=SAPRA&key=1234234&func=status&code=99999`

I wrote:

### urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rt_moke import views
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'code=(?P<code_id>\w+)/', views.Sapata, name='sapata'),
    )
```

### and views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
status = {u"99999": u'{"code": "99999","status": "undelivered"}',\
     u"88888": u'{"code": "88888","status": "delivered"}',\
     }
def Sapata(request, code_id):
    return HttpResponse(status[code_id])
```

When I request for p`ortal/client_api.ashx?client=SAPRA&key=1234234&func=status&code=99999` without `?` mark - it works, and with `?`- not. I understand, that it is query string and Django skips it in the regexp. So what can I do?

Comment: Look into `request.GET`, as mentioned in [this][1] SO question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/157295/1513010

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This URL:

```
portal/client_api.ashx?client=SAPRA&key=1234234&func=status&code=99999
```

has two parts, the path:

```
portal/client_api.ashx
```

and the query string:

```
client=SAPRA&key=1234234&func=status&code=99999
```

which is parsed into `request.GET`.

In `views.py` you should get params from request (like simple dict in `request.GET`), for example:

```
def test(request):
    code = request.GET.get('code') # here we try to get 'code' key, if not return None
    ...
```

and of course, we can't use GET params to parse URLs in `urls.py`. Your `urls.py` should looks like:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rt_moke import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^portal/client_api\.ashx$', views.Sapata, name='sapata'),
)
```

P.S. Please, don't use capital letters in names of functions.