# Cannot parse ?next= value from http://login/?next=/my_page/ using request.GET.get('next','')

Tags: django, django-views

I have a custom login url/view/template. I use the @login_required decorator for a page (let
's call it my_page) that requires login. Attempting to access

```
my_site.com/my_page
```

correctly calls

```
my_site.com/login/?next=/my_page/
```

BUT my view is unable to parse out the value of **?next=/my_page/my** and instead always redirects to my default which is **/qa/** in my view:

```
def login_with_email(request):
    error = ''
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.POST.get('email', ''):
            error = 'Please enter your email and password'
        if not request.POST.get('password', ''):
            error = 'Please enter your email and password'    
        if not error:    
            email = request.POST['email']
            password = request.POST['password']

            try:
                user = User.objects.get(email=email)
                user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=password)
                if user is not None:
                    if user.is_active:
                        login(request, user)

                        # *** 
                        next_page = request.GET.get('next', '/qa/')
                        response = HttpResponseRedirect(next_page)
                        # ***

                        response.set_cookie('login_email', email, max_age=14*24*60*60)
                        return response
            except User.DoesNotExist:    
                error = 'Invalid email and password combination'
```

Urls.py:

```
url(r'^login/$', views.login_with_email),
```

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capturing url parameters in request.GET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Comment: @niekas: Don't think so. I looked at that Q&A. I may be wrong, but I believe I followed the instructions correctly using request.GET.get.

Comment: looks like you are logged in.

Comment: is your code above indented correctly? i.e. the `try` block is inside the `if not error` block and everything is inside the `if request.method == 'POST'` block? because if Django just redirected to your view it wouldn't have been a POST request

Comment: I figured it out. I needed to use request.GET.get to get the value from the url since at that point request.method==GET and pass it my template (where I store it as a hidden field) and then access it in my view once request.method == POST. I have revised the view above with the working code and added my template code.

Comment: Now that it's solved, I'd recommend answering your own question, as it still shows as unanswered in search.

For more info, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 1):

Per my comment below, I realized I had to grab the value of next from the url **before** my POST processing (thanks to @Anentropic for flashing on the lightbulb). So now I grab the value of next, pass it to my template where I store it in a hidden field, and finally access it when required for the redirect using request.POST.get:

Revised view:

```
def login_with_email(request):
    error = ''
    next = request.GET.get('next', '/qa/profile/private/')
    if request.method == 'POST':
    ...
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    next = request.POST.get('next', '/qa/profile/private/')
                    ...    
    return render(request, 'qa/login_with_email.html', {'error': error, 'login_email': login_email, 'next': next,})
```

And in my template:

```
<form method="post" action="." autocomplete="on">{% csrf_token %} 
    <p><input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}"/></p>
    ...
```

**Note:** This answer was originally posted by the poser of the question. I just moved it here.