# Django page's filter for a ListView

Tags: python, django

I'm developing a Django App for a car rental customer.
In my model I have a Car model with their car properties (ex: passengers, ports, transmission, category, ecc...).

I had correctly setup my view and template that list all cars.
Now, I need to implement a form for filters the cars list by some characteristics.

I would like to implement in my CarListView a filter logic that filter cars by characteristics included in the query string.

ex: /cars/?ports=1&passengers=3

How can I implements this in an elegant Django way?
Is better to use a form with GET method or setup custom urls in my urls.py??

One possible solution (for other users):

```
class CarResultsView(BreadcrumbsMixin, ListView):
    queryset = Vehicle.objects.all()
    template_name = "my_app/cars.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(CarResultsView, self).get_queryset()
        search_form = VehicleFilterForm(self.request.GET)
        if search_form.is_valid():
            queryset = queryset.filter(**search_form.cleaned_data)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CarResultsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_params = self.request.GET
        context['form'] = VehicleFilterForm(get_params)
        return context
```

In your opinion, could exists one more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

This is [right in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering).

You're going to want to override the [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_queryset) method, as well as modify your URL patterns to reflect the `kwargs` you're going to be capturing.

Comment: thanks @rnevius, I've read the docs, but if I use kwargs of URL patterns how can I manage optional arguments or url? How can I retain the selected filters after any GET or POST of a form or link?
The docs contains only one filter parameter...

Comment: @rnevius : filters on a listing are usually best expressed using GET params - that's what they are for, really.

Answer (score 1):

You must define the correct regexp in your "urls.py" to capture the car parameters. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get).

Knowing the parameters, you will be able to filter the list of all cars by the needed characteristics in your view function. Something like this:

```
cars = Car.objects.filter(ports = ports, passengers = passengers)
```

Be sure to check for empty/undefined car parameters in your view. So that if the request doesn't have any parameters, all cars are displayed.

**Forms**

If you don't have previous experience with forms, read and try [Working with forms in Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/).

In your car list template, include both the search form and the filtered list. Similar to this:

```
<form action="/cars" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>

<table>
{% for car in cars %}
    <tr><td>{{ car.name }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.engine }}</td>
    <td>{{ car.price }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

When the form is submitted, a POST request is issued to your site. The GET request must show an empty form ("unbound form") and list of all cars. The template will be used to generate response both for POST and GET requests.

Comment: Thanks Mykhaylo, I know to filter Car objects inside my View, What I don't know is how can I manage the form (if the use of form is a correct way) that contains filter's input (like checkbox, input text, ecc) on my template.
I need to maintain the state of select input filter at any page request.
Ex: if I insert '5' inside the passengers form's input field, I need to pass ?passengers=5 with url (ok, I can do this with GET method), then filter cars by 5 passengers and the refresh the page with new cars list and passengers input field with number 5 inside.

Comment: I updated my answer to shortly describe how to add the search form. A more detailed explanation would be much longer, and using forms is well described in Django docs. You just have to do it yourself. But if you have more concrete questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you very much Mykhaylo. Your explanation is clear. If I would use GET method to passing search parameters on querystring, how can I maintain the state of every form field at any post back of the page? I'm using class based views.

Comment: I've edited my question, what do you think about it?