# Options to map new URL Patterns to Existing Code

Tags: django, url

I have a new caller who can call my application only in a specific new url pattern:-

```
applicationpath?send=N&msg=<MessageContent>&dest=<PHONE>&stime=MM/DD/YY HH:MM:SS PM/AM&Operator=P&Circle=Q
```

My existing urlconf calls different methods based on the message text:-

```
(('api/(?P<phone>\w+)/MessageA', handle_a_message),
 ('api/(?P<phone>\w+)/MessageB', handle_b_message),
  ...)
```

I can think of writing another urlconf that redirects to these methods along these lines:-

```
(('applicationpath?send=N&msg=MessageA&dest=(?P<phone>\w+)/\w+', handle_a_message),
 ('applicationpath?send=N&msg=MessageB&dest=(?P<phone>\w+)/\w+', handle_b_message),
 ...)
```

Are there simpler recommended alternatives I am missing? Is redirection the best alternative?

Comment: This could be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/157295/5153680

Comment: Django does not capture GET parameters in the url pattern.

Comment: Yes realized that after some effort! Thanks for confirming