# {Easy} capturing more than one url parameter in request.GET django

Tags: django, url

I am new to programming and django and I recently learned [how to capture the url parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/157295/4393101)

My question is I have a url something like below, how to capture the different parameters such as base,version,first_name, last_name

```
www.example.com/something/?base=default&version=235&first_name=darth&last_name=vader
```

Here is what I think is right

In views.py

```
def some(request):
    base = request.GET.get('base')
    version = request.GET.get('version')
    first_name = request.GET.get('first_name')
    last_name  = request.GET.get('last_name ')
```

Am I right? Where can I read more about this.

Love to learn the best practises. Thank you

Comment: you are right... but also give a default value or None like request.GET.get('last_name', '') or request.GET.get('last_name', None) for validation and default values

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.
When you access `request.GET` you access `QueryDict`. You can read more abot requests and responses in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/).

> `HttpRequest.GET`
>
> A dictionary-like object containing all given HTTP GET parameters. See
>   the [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) documentation below.

Comment: Thank you. What should be in urls.py?