# Django url r'^page/ should redirect to the same dynamic template whatever argument behind

Tags: django, django-cms

I have a little problem with my django website's urls.

In fact I have:

```
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
  url(r'^test/(?P<variable_name>\w+)/$', views.testUrl),
```

I have a dynamic page created with the name "test". redirected from the view after some treatment :

```
def testUrl(request, variable_name):
  current_site = Site.objects.get_current()
  urlTest = HttpRequest.get_full_path(request)
  parseIt = variable_name.split("/")
  ...
  for x in parseIt:
    if x == 'm':
        if ToFind[:1] == 'm':
            ID = ToFind[1:]
        else:
            ID = ToFind
        try:
            context_ret = GetId(x, api_url, ID, api_key, context_ret)
        except Exception as err:
            context_ret['message'] = err
            return render(request, 'base_templates/test.html', context_ret)
    elif x == 'z':
        try:
            context_ret = GetId(x, api_url, ToFind, api_key, context_ret)
        except Exception as err:
            context_ret['message'] = err
            return render(request, 'base_templates/test.html', context_ret)

  return render(request, 'base_templates/test.html', context_ret)
```

So if I type mydomain.org/test/ I have my dynamic page showing. Perfect.

But if I do mydomain.org/test/{whatever} I have the test.html template rendered but not the dynamic page !
Thus, the problem is that I have dynamic plugins within this dynamic page, I need to - whatever is behind test/ - use the same dynamic page. And not juste the template.

Without changing the url..

Is there a way of doing it ?

> Edit:
>
> here is an example of a call:
> domain.org/test/1923/

Comment: Because your url config, you should see the same page in /test/ and /tes/{whatever}, don't you?

Comment: I see the same page, but with /test/ I have the dynamic created page, with plugin etc. With /test/{whatever} I see the page without plugins.

Comment: Can you show the code inside your testUrl view?

Comment: I guess you pretend  `parseIt` to work with `{whatever}` in `/test/{whatever}`. am I right?

Comment: Yes, it comes from the url

Comment: If you call domain.org/test/1923/ parseIt will be `[1923]` and your code wont go into eny if statement, so where is `context_ret` defined?

Comment: Haaa you're right, it's defined initially with `context_ret = {'Default': 'defaut'}`

Comment: I changed the context_ret and everything is working now. Jeez. Thank you so much man !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to wirk with `{whatever}` comming from `/test/{whatever}`, you need to declare a variable in your url or pass `{whatever}` via `GET` variable.

Declaring a variable in url:

Change your [url definition](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/urls/) like this

```
...
url(r'^test/(?P<variable_name>\w+)/$', views.testUrl),
...
```

And catch it in the view:

```
def testUrl(request, variable_name):
    # Now if you call '/test/hithere/'
    # variable_name will take the value 'hithere'
    # you could do -> parseIt = variable_name
    ...
```

[Passing `{whatever}` via `GET` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

You can always call you url like this:

```
mydomain.org/test/?var=hithere
```

And the in your view:

```
def testUrl(request):
    parsetIt = request.GET.get('var')
    ...
```

Comment: just to be sure, variable_name is the default thing or should I write something as "(a-z)(A-Z)(0-9)" ?

Comment: @JayCee You should replace variable_name with a verbose name for your variable.

Comment: Ok because this variable is independent of me. I mean it can be /test/f/numbers or /test/k/m98324 etc

Comment: @JayCee you should use the right regex depending on what value do you expect to get in variable_name, check the first link I provided in my answer

Comment: So I tried it, but I am back to my original problem haha.
It's weird, because the template call is the good one, `base_templates/test.html` but plugins are not showing. As if it was a different page or just the template requested, ignoring the dynamic page created.

Comment: @JayCee Add your changes to your post

Comment: @JayCee Please add an example, how are you calling your url, what value are you passing.