# Django: Make query using url ( Assigning variable using url )

Tags: python, django, http

I am trying to make a query system for my website, i think the best way and the most compact would be to assign search variable using url pattern.

So for example, i want to search objects of model `User`:

---

User sends HttpRequest to following url:

`https://127.0.0.1/search/q="admin"`

Now HttpRequest is also sent to `search` view, we somehow get `q` variable data.

```
def search(request):
    for query in User.objects.all():
        if q in query: # < We somehow need to get data of 'q'.
           return HttpResponse(q)
```

Since i have admin in `User.objects.all()`, this should return HttpResponse of 'admin'.

---

How can this url pattern be made? So i can assign `q` variable from the url and then send it to system to find it?

Comment: You can use query parameters, but for this your url should look like the following: `https://127.0.0.1/search/?q=admin` (note the question mark). 
Then, in your view, you can access all of your query parameters using `request.GET[param]` (in your case `request.GET['q']`). You can read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) wiki article to find out more about query parameters.

Comment: Did you have a look at this question already? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get
The official documentation on how to handle GET-parameters in Django can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.GET

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have problems with this URL:

```
https://127.0.0.1/search/q="admin"
```

There is no `?` in the URL, so there is no query string, it's all part of the "path". Using characters like `=` and `"` in there will confuse a lot of things, if it works at all.

Either just do

```
https://127.0.0.1/search/admin
```

With an URL pattern like `r'^search/(?P<querystring>.+)$'`, or

```
https://127.0.0.1/search/?q=admin
```

In this case the query string will be in `request.GET['q']`; it's also possible to use [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) to process query parameters (e.g. for validating them).

Comment: I knew the first method, but didn't find it as good design, second method is what i needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture named strings from URLs like this:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^blog/page(?P<num>[0-9]+)/$', views.page),
]
```

views.py:

```
def page(request, num="1"):
```