# Django. Record is not deleted properly

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I'm having a problem hope you could help me please.

I got these models:

```
MODELS = (
('A', 'A'),
('B', 'B'),
)


class person(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=128,choices=MODELS, default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre


class person_A(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    hobbies = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.nombre

class person_B(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(person, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(default=10)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.person.nombre
```

As you can see I have `person_A`, `person_B` which will be saved in my database.

Here's my view:

```
def get_person(request):
    titulo = 'Person'
    qs_a = person_A.objects.all()
    qs_b = person_B.objects.all()
    qs = chain(qs_b,qs_a)
    form = person_aForm(request.POST or None)
    form2 = personForm(request.POST or None)
    form4 = person_bForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        "qs_a": qs_a,
        "qs_b": qs_b,
        "qs": qs,
        "form2": form2,
        "form": form,
        "form4": form4,
        "titulo": titulo,
    }
    form2_valid = form2.is_valid()
    form_valid = form.is_valid()
    form4_valid = form4.is_valid()
    if form2_valid:
        person = form2.save()
        if form_valid:
            person_a = form.save(commit=False)
            person_a.person = person
            person_a.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Se ha guardado satisfactoriamente')
            return redirect("get_person")
        if form4_valid:
            person_b = form4.save(commit=False)
            person_b.person = person
            person_b.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Se ha guardado satisfactoriamente')
            return redirect("get_person")
    return render(request, "person.html", context)
```

Here as you can see is being saved my form for `person_A` or `person_B`.

Here's my delete function:

```
def delete_person(request,id):
    try:
        qs = person_B.objects.all()
        instance = get_object_or_404(qs, id=id)
        instance.delete()
        messages.success(request, 'B')
    except:
        try: 
            qs = person_A.objects.all()
            instance = get_object_or_404(qs, id=id)
            instance.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'A')
        except:
            pass
    return redirect('get_person')
```

My url:

```
url(r'^delete_person/(?P<id>\d+)/$',views.delete_person, name='delete_person'),
```

Template:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for item in qs  %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ item.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.person.model }}</td>
        <td>{{ item.person.nombre }}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'delete_person' item.id %}">Delete</a></td>
      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically, I'm having two different models which everyone is being saved in the database and being shown in a `table`. To do that I used `chain()` from `itertools`. I joined Person A and Person B to show them both in one `table`. This is working fine, now here's my problem:

If `person_A` has the same `id` as `person_B` and I want to delete `person_A`, it will delete `person_B` instead. I know this is because of the `chain()` but i'd like to know if there's a possible way to solve this?

**Thank you!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the fact that `delete_function()` always tries to delete `person_B` first. Unless an exception is thrown, `person_A` will never be deleted. If an exception is thrown, you will still delete `person_B` first, since it is inside `try:` block, hence an attempt to delete it always precedes an attempt to delete `person_A`. By the way, the way your code is written now, *any* exception will result in an attempt to delete `person_A`. I would suggest using a more specific exception, or otherwise you might run into really confusing bugs later on.

As for the solution, I'm sure there are more clever ways out, but couple of quick-and-dirty solutions I can think of right now:

1. Defining a custom [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters), which would check what type of class the `person` is and act accordingly (e.g., call different delete methods for different classes; pass a flag as [query parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get) and use it in the `delete_person()` method to determine which `person_` to delete).
2. What I would probably do: instead of chaining instances of models, iterate over them separately and call delete methods suited for a specific model:

   ```
    <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>
      ...
      {% for item in qs_a %}
        <tr>
          <td>... delete_person_A() ...</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
      {% for item in qs_b %}
        <tr>
          <td>... delete_person_B() ...</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
   ```

   If I recall correctly, `chain()` iterates over first iterable until it is exhausted, and only then does it iterate over the second one. Hence, iterating over the `qs_a` and `qs_b` separately should not make a huge difference in the output. While this way you will have to write slightly more code, it will also be a bit more simple and explicit - hence, easier to understand and refactor later, if there is a need.

Comment: Thank you sir, your answer helped me a lot

Comment: I used your second method so far, I think that's the easiest one and until now worked perfect.