# (django) url regex doesn't match

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

The url I try: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest/archive/?page=1`.
The regex pattern:

1. (The original one I tried): `r'^archive/(?P<reverse>[n]{0,1})/?\?page=[0-9]+/?'`
2. (An easier I also tried in the python console.) `r'^archive/\?page=[0-9]+'`
3. (The easiest possible, just to try.) `r'^archive/\?page=1'` (But I escaped the question mark in the right way, don't I?)

I tried all of these regexes in the python console and they worked nice, so I think the problem isn't about a wrong regex.

**So: why don't this work?**

---

**Optional information:**

the projects url-conf:

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
  url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('manifest:index'))),
  url(r'^manifest/', include('manifest.urls', namespace='manifest')),
]
```

note: the url `127.0.0.1:8000/manifest/index` matches as it should, so can't be about everything is made wrong.

---

**The url traceback:**

`Page not found (404)`

`Request Method:    GET`

`Request URL:   http://127.0.0.1:8000/manifest/archive/?page=1`

`Using the URLconf defined in asqiir005.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:`

```
^admin/
^$
^manifest/ ^$ [name='index']
^manifest/ ^(?P<number>[0-9]+)$ [name='article']
^manifest/ ^archive/\?page=1
^manifest/ ^archive/(?P<reverse>[n]{0,1})/?\?page=[0-9]+/? [name='paged_archive']
^manifest/ ^archive/all/(?P<reverse>[n]{0,1})/?$ [name='whole_archive']
^media\/(?P<path>.*)$
```

`The current URL, manifest/archive/, didn't match any of these.`

Comment: Do we really need to handle query params in urls? I think we don't need to.
The following url pattern should work fine :
url(r'^archive/', view_to_handle),

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your file *manifest.urls* :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^archive/?$', view_to_handle),
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use request.GET.get('page', '') in your views.

Other options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/150518/3336408