# How to use captured value from URL to select JSON data in Django

Tags: json, django, url

Let's assume that I have GET request with URL `domain/search/?value=123` and data in JSON:

```
[

      {
        "id": 1,
        "value": 123,
        "value2": 123123
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "value": 1,
        "value2": 214
      }

]
```

I would like to get data where `value = 123`. In this case:

```
    [

          {
            "id": 1,
            "value": 123,
            "value2": 123123
          }
    ]
```

I have found information how to capture parameters from URL in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get) post. I wonder what I should do now to find best solution in Django. Thanks in advance.

How can I use it in views.py:

```
if request.method == 'GET':
        myObject = myObjectClass.objects.all()
        serializer = myObjectSerializer(myObject, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

when data from JSON is not only an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to get it in python:

```
data = [

  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 123,
    "value2": 123123
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 1,
    "value2": 214
  }

]
result = None
for item in data:
    if item['value'] == 123:
       result = [item]
       break

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript code to do this :-

```
function test()
{
//alert("Hi");
var text = '[{"id":1,"value":123,"value2":123123},{"id":2,"value":1,"value2":214}]'

json = JSON.parse(text);

var result = [];

for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    var obj = json[i];
    if(obj['value'] == 123){
        result.push(obj);
    }

}

console.log(result);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In views.py , you can get the value of the URL through request object

```
    data = [

  {
    "id": 1,
    "value": 123,
    "value2": 123123
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "value": 1,
    "value2": 214
  }

]
print [ item for item in data if item['value'] == request.GET.get('value') ]
```