# Django: Add optional parameters to a request in the view

Tags: python, django, view, request

In my Django app's `views.py` I'm passing in a GET request to a function definition. How do I check for an optional parameter in that request (like `&optional='All'`) and if that optional parameter is missing, add it. This is all before the request is sent to the template to be rendered.

This is what I have so far:

```
def my_function(request):

    #get all the optional parameters 
    optional_params_list = request.GET.keys()

    #see if filter_myfilter is NOT an optional param
    if 'filter_myfilter' not in optional_params_list:
      #add filter_myfilter as a parameter and set it equal to All
      request.filter_myfilter = 'All'

    return render(request, 'quasar.html')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Answer (score 0):

In your view, you have access to `request.GET`, With it you can set new value to a specific URL from that view. As you mentioned, add the `optional` value to GET parameter is possible. So we can proceed by redirecting the user to the correct view in case the value `optional` is missing or not equal to `All`.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def my_function(request):

    param = request.GET.get('param','All')
    if param != 'All':
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('url_name') + "?optional=All")
        # or
        # return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path + "?optional=All")
    return render(request, 'quasar.html')
```