# request.GET.get('q', None) always returns None

Tags: django

```
# my .views
def search_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q', None)
    print(query)
    context = {"query": query}
    return render(request, 'view.html', context)
```

```
# .urls
path('search/', search_view)
```

```
# my view.html
{% if query %}

        <p>Your query {{ query }}</p>
        {% else %}

        <form method="GET" action='/search/'>
            <input type="search" name='q' placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>

        {% endif %}
```

I'm new to Django and I'm following the docs, I looked over and over and seems right to me but I keep getting query=None. When I input a value in the search bar goes to http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=value,
but the query is always None. Please help a noob getting started.

Comment: Is that your actual code? It looks ok to me.

Comment: I copied and tested the same code and works, @Brocante.

Comment: I think there was some conflicts in url's paths because pressing the search button didn't send me to the 'view.html' template, works now but still have no exact idea about where the error was

Answer (score 0):

welcome to SO! Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)? From reading this, it seems like you are having some issues returning your value back from the form to your function.

Comment: I checked it but was not helpful, but I got where the problem is, the url doesn't load the right template

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are looking at at the end, but that  is not a good job. did you try an < a > tag too?

< a href="search/?q=sth">