# Django: unable to read POST parameters sent by payment gateway

Tags: python, django, post, payment-gateway

I am unable to read POST parameters sent by payment gateway after payment was processed. Payment gateway redirects to `returnUrl` (I pass this to payment gateway before payment was processed) with some parameters by POST request.

In url.py

```
path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
```

in views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
@login_required
def cashfree_response(request):
    print(request.method)
    if request.method == "POST":
        print('inside post method')
        print(request.POST.get('cf_subReferenceId'))
    if request.method == "GET":
        print('inside get method')
        print(request.GET.get('cf_subReferenceId'))
```

`print(request.method)` is showing as `GET` but it was supposed be `POST` method also `print(request.GET.get('cf_subReferenceId'))` and `print(request.POST.get('cf_subReferenceId'))` are showing as `None`.

But it looks like payment gateway sending parameters as POST method. When I pass `returnUrl` as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/`  ('/' is missing in the first one) then I am getting error as

`You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.`

but I see in my google chrome page that payment gateway sending parameters with POST request. Below image shows parameters sent by payment gateway by POST request

[image]

If I change urls.py to

```
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
```

in settings.py to

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
```

and `returnUrl` to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse` then I am not getting any error but still not receiving any parameters. How do I read those parameters sent by payment gateway by POST request? [Here](https://docs.cashfree.com/docs/sbc/guide/#payment-response) is the documentation for payment gateway.

**Update:**

I tried all different combinations of APPEND_SLASH, urls.py and returnUrl. It didn't work in any case. Below are the types of issues I got with each combination.

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/'

APPEND_SLASH = True
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse'

APPEND_SLASH = False
path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/'

APPEND_SLASH = False
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse'
```

For all the above combinations django is redirecting as GET method and POST data was lost.

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse'
```

for this case I am getting below error

You called this URL via POST, but the URL doesn't end in a slash and you have APPEND_SLASH set. Django can't redirect to the slash URL while maintaining POST data. Change your form to point to 127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/ (note the trailing slash), or set APPEND_SLASH=False in your Django settings.

```
APPEND_SLASH = True
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/'

APPEND_SLASH = False
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/'
```

for these both cases, I am getting csrf verification failed error.

```
APPEND_SLASH = False
path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse'
```

for this case, I got page not found error.

Comment: 1. Have you tried other combinations? For example, urls.py without slash and APPEND_SLASH equals to True. 2. Where do you set returnUrl? In Cashfree? can it be  http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse/? 
I think, as the trackeback says,that Django is redirecting your URL and loosing the POST data while doing it

Comment: @javidazac Yes, I tried all different combinations of APPEND_SLASH, urls.py and returnUrl. I updated the question with that information. I pass returnUrl as a parameter when I makes request to the Cashfree payment gateway.

Comment: hi @javidazac, do you know answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327185/django-all-auth-create-account-with-email-unique-constraint-failed-display-m)

Comment: hi @javidazac, I am sorry to ask you again but do you know answer for this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123264/django-how-to-generate-activate-url-that-django-allauth-generates-for-email-con?noredirect=1#comment110158933_62123264).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@login_required` decorator was causing the issue. I think `@login_required` redirecting the page to see if user logged in (even if user already logged in) then redirecting back to this view. During this process, it is loosing POST data and converting the request method to GET.

Answer (score 0):

`APPEND_SLASH` *shouldn't* matter, as it only affects URLs that cannot be found, but you are explicitly specifying a URL pattern without a slash. So the issue is with your path definition.

Assuming we are talking about the main, project-level urls.py, the correct setting would be:

```
path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
returnUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/cashfreeresponse'
```

But my guess is that your path named `cashfree_response` is defined in an app (e.g. `polls/urls.py`) and that it is included at a subpath in the project-level (e.g. `mysite/urls`) like that:

```
path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
```

In that case, the correct `returnUrl` would be `http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/cashfreeresponse`.

Instead of hard-coding the URL, you can use `reverse` together with request.

```
from django.urls import reverse
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('cashfreeresponse')
```

Note: You might have to use `reverse('<appname>:cashfreeresponse')` here, e.g. `reverse('polls:cashfreeresponse')`

**Edit:** from your update, it seems like you still have a trailing slash in the path definition:

```
    path('cashfreeresponse/',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
```

Change that to:

```
    path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response'),
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, It didn't work. It is still redirecting the POST request as GET after following your suggestion. It was inside app 'pages'. So I used `path('polls/', include('polls.urls'))` and `from django.urls import reverse` and  `requestUrl =
request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('cashfreeresponse'))` then I passed requestUrl to payment gateway.

Comment: please post the full urls.py of your project and of the app containing the `cashfree_response` view

Comment: I updated the question with urls.py of the project and the pages app

Comment: I tried both ways. I got the same result with or without slash.

Comment: It still must be without slash. `returnUrl` should be `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/cashfreeresponse"`, please verify.

Comment: I tried again now with `path('cashfreeresponse',views.cashfree_response, name='cashfree_response')` and `returnUrl = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('cashfree_response'))` and I did verify the returnUrl before passing by `print(returnUrl)` and it printed as `http://127.0.0.1:8000/pages/cashfreeresponse`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209463/discussion-between-daniel-hepper-and-sreekanthkura7).