# Comparison in Django template using request.GET and choices is not properly evaluated

Tags: django, comparison

I have this in my models:

```
class Task(Record):

    class Status(models.IntegerChoices):
        OPEN = 1, "Open"
        COMPLETED = 2, "Completed"
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=Status.choices, db_index=True, default=1)
```

Then in my template I want to show all the statuses, so I do this in views.py:

```
context = { 
  "statuses": Task.Status.choices,
}
```

And in my template I loop through it:

```
{% for label,name in statuses %}
  {{ label }}: {{ name }}
{% endfor %}
```

This leads to:

```
1: Open
2: Completed
```

So far, so good. But now if I use a GET parameter, I can't get things to work as I want. Say I open ?id=2 and then I run:

```
{% for label,name in statuses %}
  {{ label }}: {{ name }} 
  {% if label == request.GET.id %}
     YES
  {% else %} 
     Sorry, not equal to {{ request.GET.id }}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Then I expect this to show YES for the first item. But it doesn't! Somehow this evaluates to:

```
1: Open Sorry, not equal to 1 
2: Completed Sorry, not equal to 1
```

I do not understand why the first item does not evaluate to true.

Comment: is label string type or int ?

Comment: It comes from the choice list, eg        OPEN = 1, "Open" -> I guess it's int...

Comment: Should the variable type be equal for this to evaluate to true? If so, is there a way to still evaluate this if true if the type is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view to store this value into context and pass with template . Get data from request like this

> ```
> request.GET.get('id')
> ```

and make sure data type of both must be same otherwise you will always execute else condition.

[Capturing url parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Comment: That syntax makes sense in the views.py file, but in this case I'm working in the template and that doesn't work (Could not parse the remainder... error).

Comment: OK noted, but does that mean that you can not do these kinds of comparisons directly in the templates? Do you know the reason?

Comment: NOTE: I actually had to type cast the request.GET["id"] as integer, only then would it work.

Comment: You can do comparison in templates but same data type needed.