# Get all parameters and their values in a request in Django

Tags: python, django, http, parameters

I have a get request being sent to my Django project with a list of parameters.

```
GET /site/login?
_name=bill&_last_name=Smith&_favorite_food=wings
```

I need to get each parameter and it's value.  What would be the best way to do this?  I know that in Django you can do print(request.data) but I need the parameters.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Comment: That does help.  Is there a way to just get all parameters or do you need to specify each one individually?

Comment: `request.GET` will give you a dict of your parameters in get request