# Making different views from similar (but slightly different) information?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I know there is a better way to do this, but I can't quite figure it out.

I am making a web application that has a series of the same pages, based on what department and station you select.

This is info that I am using later in a separate script to determine where to send a file.

But right now I am using different views for each page.

For example I have one view in my views.py that looks like this:

views.py

```
def FOO_station_0(request):
    Site_Data.station = 0
    Site_Data.dept = "FOO"
    ctx = {}
    ctx['station'] = Site_Data.station

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = my_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                Ext_Data.parsed_data = form.cleaned_data['full_scan']
                saveScan()
            except IndexError:
                ctx['error_message'] = error_message
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/input')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/confirm')

    else:
        form = my_form()
    ctx['form'] = form
    return render(request, f'scan/FOO/FOO_station.html', ctx)
```

And another that looks like this:

```
def BAR_station_2(request):
    Site_Data.station = 2
    Site_Data.dept = "BAR"
    ctx = {}
    ctx['station'] = Site_Data.station

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = my_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                Ext_Data.parsed_data = form.cleaned_data['full_scan']
                saveScan()
            except IndexError:
                ctx['error_message'] = error_message
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/input')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/confirm')

    else:
        form = my_form()
    ctx['form'] = form
    return render(request, f'scan/BAR/BAR_station.html', ctx)
```

As you can see, they are both returning the same HTML file, this is because they are very similar, but I want the URL, and the information passed to be different.

I need to do this for many different stations, all having a different dept or station number, but other than that it will be the same.

I could just add one view for each station, but that feels sloppy.

My Urls.py looks like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
...
...
    path('FOO/station_0', views.FOO_station_0, name='FOO_station_0'),
    path('FOO/station_1', views.FOO_station_1, name='FOO_station_0'),
    path('FOO/station_2', views.FOO_station_2, name='FOO_station_0'),
    path('FOO/station_3', views.FOO_station_3, name='FOO_station_0'),
...
...
    path('BAR/station_1', views.BAR_station_1, name='BAR_station_1'),
    path('BAR/station_2', views.BAR_station_2, name='BAR_station_2'),
    path('BAR/station_3', views.BAR_station_3, name='BAR_station_3'),
    path('BAR/station_4', views.BAR_station_4, name='BAR_station_4'),
...
...
]
```

Where each station is returning a different URL, because that URL is linked to the data that I want passed.

It doesn't seem like this is the best way to do this, but I don't know where to start to find a better way.

What is the best way to do this in Django?

Any help is very much appreciated.

---

Besides the answers given below, this link was also helpful for anyone who finds this question in the future.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial03/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `station` and `dept` are the only things that change you can add them as the arguments of function:

```
def station_view(request, dept, station_num):
    Site_Data.dept = dept
    Site_Data.station = station_num
    ctx = {}
    ctx['station'] = Site_Data.station

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = my_form(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            try:
                Ext_Data.parsed_data = form.cleaned_data['full_scan']
                saveScan()
            except IndexError:
                ctx['error_message'] = error_message
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/error/input')

            return HttpResponseRedirect(f'/confirm')

    else:
        form = my_form()
    ctx['form'] = form
    # assuming dept will always be either 'FOO' or 'BAR'
    return render(request, f'scan/{dept}/{dept}_station.html', ctx)
```

Then in `urls.py` define those parameters in url as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
...
    path('<dept>/station_<station_num>/', views.station_view, name='station-view'),
]
```

Finally in templates, you can relate each object's `station` and `dept` with something like below:

```
{% for obj in objects %}
    <a href="url 'station-view' dept=obj.dept station_num=obj.station">obj.name<>
{% endfor %}
```

PS: I assume your context object name is `objects` and it actually contains fields `dept`, `station` and `name`. Fit it for your needs.

Comment: Wow, very thorough answer. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

first you need to use regex in you urls. by doing this you will have one or a few urls instead of too many. This is the link how you can do this [capture parameters from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

In the link above, you will see how to capture parameters from url, then you can use those parameters inside your view. By doing this you will have one or a few views, and you will not need to add one view for each url.

Comment: I was not aware that more parameters could be passed in like that. Though, now that I see it, it definitely makes sense. I appreciate you taking the time to help me out. I am going to play around with it and make sure this fits my needs before marking the question as solved.