# Django - how to match URL pattern regex with additional parameters?

Tags: django, regex, django-urls

I have the following endpoint at my urls.py

```
url(r'^stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f-]+)$', App_Views.stream, name='stream'),
```

That would mean that the endpoint would look like this on call:

```
http://localhost/stream/5409caac-fc9c-42b8-90af-058eff65a156
```

Now I'm adding some extra parameters to the URL before calling it, so that it looks like this:

```
http://localhost/stream/5409caac-fc9c-42b8-90af-058eff65a156?st=zD3H0cHJrbcUAHZPNbPGyg&e=1630915404
```

Now to my actual question, how does the regex at urls.py has to look like in order to accept the second URL example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Comment: @NKSM Not really sure about that as the question you showed alway works with "/?" and dont have any "/" beside I dont need to capture the parameters, I simply want it to match the regex

Comment: Have you tried that ?  r'^stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f-=&?]+)$'

Comment: Still leads to: django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'stream' with keyword arguments '{'pk': '5409caac-fc9c-42b8-90af-058eff65a156?st=uARN1o52zWjBTPgGZmxyMw&e=1630917248'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f-=&?]+)$']

Comment: Well, I got it working, like this:

url(r'^stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-zA-Z-=&?]+)$',

Thze primary key was is uuid so its just [0-9a-f-]+ but everything behind it is upper and lower case a-z, A-Z,0-9

Answer (score 1):

The usage of `url()` is [deprecated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urls/#url) already. Use `re_path()` instead.

Given this is your URL:

```
http://localhost/stream/5409caac-fc9c-42b8-90af-058eff65a156?st=zD3H0cHJrbcUAHZPNbPGyg&e=1630915404
```

I assume the extra parameters are specifically:

```
?st=zD3H0cHJrbcUAHZPNbPGyg&e=1630915404
```

All of that string that starts from the character `?` is already part of the [query string parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string). In Django, the URL pattern matching is only for the actual path, not including the query string. This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/urls/#what-the-urlconf-searches-against):

> ### What the URLconf searches against
>
> The URLconf searches against the requested URL, as a normal Python
> string. This does not include GET or POST parameters, or the domain
> name.
>
> For example, in a request to **`https://www.example.com/myapp/`**, the
> URLconf will look for **`myapp/`**.
>
> In a request to **`https://www.example.com/myapp/?page=3`**, the URLconf
> will look for **`myapp/`**.
>
> The URLconf doesn’t look at the request method. In other words, all
> request methods – POST, GET, HEAD, etc. – will be routed to the same
> function for the same URL.

So this should still work:

```
re_path(r'^stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-f-]+)$', App_Views.stream, name='stream'),
```

If you need to access the values of the query string, access the `request.GET` within the receiving view.

Comment: No really sure onto that, for me it has to look like this: re_path(r'^stream/(?P<pk>[0-9a-zA-Z-=_&?]+)$

I generating the /stream url using a template decorator so django expects that this pattern matches upon rendering the template. But re_path is a good practice anyways.

Comment: What do you mean you are not sure with that? Have you tried `re_path`? I tried it with `re_path` and your original regex worked with no modification, no need to match the additional characters `"?"`, `"="`, and `"&"`. It is also as documented.