# Access query parameters using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, axios

I am using React in the frontend and Django in the backend and I am currently doing the API integration for which I am using Axios.

So in the frontend side I am calling a URL like this

`http://localhost:3000/attempt/?quiz_id=6`

and I want the quiz_id = 6 so that I can use this afterward to access data in the backend.

I am using Functional components if that helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at axios's  documentation in [github](https://github.com/axios/axios#example)

If what you want to do is a GET request this should be enough:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/attempt/?quiz_id=6')
  .then((res) => {
    // handle success
    console.log(res);
  })
```

Also you have available this kind of usage:

```js
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/attempt', {
  params: {
    quiz_id: 6
  }
}).then((res) => {
   // handle success
   console.log(res);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the quiz_id from the URL, I know how to send the get request.

Comment: Oh I understand now, the question is redacted very very poorly, note everybody understood the same as me!

Comment: This question is duplicated, you have hundreds of answers about this, for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too:

```
const data =  await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/attempt/?quiz_id=6').then(res => res.data);
```

Comment: I want the quiz_id from the URL, I know how to send the get request

Answer (score 0):

You can include dynamic `quiz_id` by using params. The way for this is to making an axios request using the id of the param that you want to update and return:

Your code will read like so:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:3000/attempt/${quiz_id}', quiz_id);
```