# How to get cookie values when it's coming different subdomains?

Tags: python, php, django, cookies, python-requests

I have a cookie value set in wordpress site and I would need to read this value when the page redirects to the app which is a django backend. How do I retrieve this value in the app?

So this value should persist from `www.example.com` to `app.example.com`

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get

Comment: See also "[Subdomains and Logins](/q/1442017/90527)", "[Can't set a cross subdomain cookie in Django](/q/67957308/90527)", "[How to share Django sessions across newly added subdomains](/q/49835929/90527)", "[When using sub-domains for a Django site, how can you share django logins across sub-domains on localhost?](/q/1442081/90527)"