# Djnago - dynamically change order_by field (need to do it from swagger)

Tags: python, django, swagger, sql-order-by

I've got a question. How to manage to change ordering thru the swagger. For example I've got a Menu model with fields: name and dishes. By GET I retrieve a list of menus and I would like to be able to choose in swagger if queryset should be ordered by name (alphabetically) or ordered by the numbers of dishes in menu (descending).

I managed to do something similar with filtering the queryset:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do2yf.png)
But I can't find solution for switching the ordering.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capturing URL parameters in request.GET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at how [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) does it, you can use HTTP query parameters `localhost:8000/page?order_by=name`. Take a look at the [QueryDict API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) and this other StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150505/capturing-url-parameters-in-request-get) as it's really similar.